# Promtail with logrotated tar log files

Tags: tar, grafana-loki

I am using promtail to parse log files that are being rotated daily as a gzip file. What is best solution to parse these files?

In scenario #1 the file some.log is rotated to some-2021-08-11.log so in the promtail config file I use path=some-*.log which works well.

In scenario #2 the file someother.log is rotated to someother-2021-08-11.log.gz, I need some way to read those from promtail.

I was thinking of unzipping the log files but that would need to be done each days and older files (more then 7 days) would have to be manually deleted. I also thought of reading the someother.log file before it is rotated and zipped but the positions file would need to be reset every days.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to configure promtail with the following:

```
path=some.log
```

Before the rotation, every log line will pass to the "some.log" file and, because of that, it will be sent to Loki. This is enough, you don't need to worry about rotated files.

Comment: but the file some.log gets reset every day so the positions file needs to also be reset1 
i.e. say on day 1 there was 3 lines the position file will say have read up to line 3; on day 2 some.log gets wiped out and we get 3 new first lines, promtail wont read these as it believe the were read on day 1

Comment: Don't worry about this, the positions file will be reset every time the rotation happens.